Trying to embed files in column G8 onwards displayicon as true
Trying to embed files in column G8 onwards displayicon as true. Width etc.
    Sub InsertObjectsFromFiles()
        Dim ws As Worksheet
        Dim lastRow As Long
        Dim filePath As String
        Dim i As Long
        Dim obj As OLEObject
        Dim fileExists As Boolean
        
        ' Set the worksheet you are working on
        Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change Sheet1 to your sheet name
    
        ' Find the last row with data in column F
        lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    
        ' Loop through rows from row 8 to the last used row in column F
        For i = 8 To lastRow
            ' Get the file path from column F
            filePath = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
            
            ' Check if the file path is not empty
            If filePath <> "" Then
                ' Check if the file exists
                fileExists = Dir(filePath) <> ""
                
                If fileExists Then
                    On Error Resume Next
                    ' Insert object from file, display as icon
                    Set obj = ws.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Package", FileName:=filePath, _
                                                Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                                                IconLabel:=Dir(filePath), Left:=ws.Cells(i, "G").Left, _
                                                Top:=ws.Cells(i, "G").Top, Width:=100, Height:=100)
                    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
                        MsgBox "Error inserting file: " & filePath & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
                        Err.Clear
                    End If
                    On Error GoTo 0
                Else
                    MsgBox "File not found: " & filePath, vbExclamation
                End If
            End If
        Next i
    End Sub

Getting error as:

Run-time error '1004':
Unable to get the Add property of the OLEObjects dass


"You must specify either ClassType or FileName. A string that contains the programmatic identifier for the object to be created. If ClassType is specified, FileName and Link are ignored." https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.oleobjects.add#:~:text=If%20ClassType%20is%20specified%2C%20FileName%20and%20Link%20are%20ignored.

This should work
Sub InsertObjectsFromFiles()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim filePath As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim obj As OLEObject
    Dim fileExists As Boolean
    
    ' Set the worksheet you are working on
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change Sheet1 to your sheet name

    ' Find the last row with data in column F
    lastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row

    ' Loop through rows from row 8 to the last used row in column F
    For i = 8 To lastRow
        ' Get the file path from column F
        filePath = ws.Cells(i, "F").Value
        
        ' Check if the file path is not empty
        If filePath <> "" Then
            ' Check if the file exists
            fileExists = Dir(filePath) <> ""
            
            If fileExists Then
                On Error GoTo ErrHandler
                ' Insert object from file, display as icon
                Set obj = ws.OLEObjects.Add(Filename:=filePath, _
                                            Link:=False, DisplayAsIcon:=True, _
                                            IconLabel:=Dir(filePath), Left:=ws.Cells(i, "G").Left, _
                                            Top:=ws.Cells(i, "G").Top, Width:=50, Height:=50)
                
                ' If no error, proceed
                On Error GoTo 0
            Else
                MsgBox "File not found: " & filePath, vbExclamation
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    
    Exit Sub
    
ErrHandler:
    MsgBox "Error inserting file: " & filePath & vbCrLf & "Error: " & Err.Description, vbCritical
    Err.Clear
    Resume Next
End Sub

